# Reloading python terminal after user input with a new output

Tags: python, terminal

I would like to create simple terminal app where user will have 4 choices. 3 numbers and one function that will create new 3 numbers and then create new terminal with newly created numbers. I tried terminal libraries , putting function into dictionary or list.

My question is how to call function so it will create desired output?

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

def main():
   def creation():
      num1 = random.randint(1,50)
      num2 = random.randint(1,50)
      num3 = random.randint(1,50)
      numbers = ['Again']
      numbers.append(num1)
      numbers.append(num2)
      numbers.append(num3)
      return numbers
   numbers = creation()
   
   while True:
       for numby in numbers:
           print(f'{numby} : {numbers.index(numby)}')
       choose = int(input('choose option: '))
       if choose > 0:
          print(numbers[choose])
          # continue task
       if choose == 0:
          main()
          break
main()
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
0 : Again
1 : num1 # for example 33
2 : num2 # for example 44
3 : num3 # for example 46
choose option:
```

User types 0
and new menu will be generated

```
0 : Again
1 : num1 # now for example 12
2 : num2 # now for example 22
3 : num3 # now for example 38
choose option:
```

Comment: From the code you've provided it is not clear what you're asking and what problem do you have. Please, clarify your question and provide us with undestandable question.

Comment: I edited the post I hope it is bit more understandable now

Comment: If you want a new set of numbers in each loop, then you need to do `numbers = creation()` inside the loop, not outside.  That's all it takes.  By the way, do NOT use recursion for this.  That is, do not have `main` call `main`.  Just do nothing, and the loop will be run again.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. Also check out the `enumerate()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
import random
def creation():
  numbers = ['Again']
  numbers.append(random.randint(1,50))
  numbers.append(random.randint(1,50))
  numbers.append(random.randint(1,50))
  return numbers

def main():   
   while True:
       numbers = creation()
       for numby, number in enumerate(numbers):
           print(f'{numby} : {number}')
       choose = int(input('choose option: '))
       if choose == 0:
          continue
       if choose > 0:
          print(numbers[choose])
          break
main()
```